# CodeIgniter Cannot Locate Model When Using SSL

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I seem to be having an SSL issue with a site I am developing using CodeIgniter.  I am using a wildcard SSL certificate issued via Thawte that has been verified and properly installed.  However it seems I am having a problem with CodeIgniter locating models when I access it through the secure URL.

When I access the following URL via https, I get an error that CI cannot locate the model.

https://takeoff.specwise.com/index.php/admin/

I believe this is an SSL issue because if I access the same page via a regular insecure URL, the page loads as it should:

http://takeoff.specwise.com/index.php/admin/

I have been reading all the information I can regarding SSL & CodeIgniter, both here and on the CodeIgniter forums, but I can't seem to find a fix for my specific problem.

If anybody has any thoughts or ideas as to what is going wrong or how I can correct the issue, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check: you can access your main page (index.php) OK with https?

Are you using Apache? You might want to check that you don't have some settings (redirections, rewrites) in your apache conf that apply only to the http virtual site. I once had the apache settings for my site in a virtual name host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
....
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously, that does not apply to https, so in that case you'd need to change the 80 to a *, or define another virtual host for your https site.

Comment: Hi Leon,

Thank you for the reply.  I can access my /index.php/ site via https without any problems.  But that is a very simple controller for now and does not load any models, just loads some views.

https://takeoff.specwise.com/index.php

This is actually a Windows server unfortunately, not my server of choice, so .htaccess would not apply.  It is IIS 6.  I have checked the settings and do not see any redirects or rewrites besides how CodeIgniter handles URL rewrites via the software.